# Call to undefined WordPress function get_header() errors, but header is still displayed

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom WordPress theme, more specifically the `index.php` file. When I navigate to my website main page, the header is displayed correctly, but occasionally errors show in the server log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\OryTheme\index.php:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\OryTheme\index.php on line 1
```

I don't know why it gives an error if it displays the header. Also, if I remove `<?php get_header(); ?>`, the header won't get displayed. Can I ignore these errors?

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you or someone else tries to visit a URL like this: https://yoursite.dev/wp-content/themes/OryTheme

You should get an `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in ....` error.

Most likely you or someone else is hitting that direct theme directory of your website and it's executing `index.php` but unfortunately, you won't get any wordpress functions there. So it's logging an error.

If you would like to get rid of this types of errors. You can always put a code like this in the beginning of PHP files of your custom theme and plugins.

```
<?php 
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // don't allow to call the file directly

// start coding here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really understand what you mean by hitting the direct theme directory. I'm hosting the server in Azure, and sometimes when I navigate to my main page (thus loading my theme's `index.php`), the azure server console shows the error. Though, as I said, the header gets loaded perfectly fine, and the theme won't work without that line.

Comment: By the word 'hitting', I mean to visit that URL. Just try using these code, into `index.php` and you should never get that error in your log. https://pastebin.com/jhuJbHz3

Comment: FYI, `if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;` this lines of code just to check if WordPress is executing/including that file. If this file is getting called manually from somewhere it will just exit rather than throwing an error.